# What kind of learning is feature generation for score maximization?

Tags: machine-learning, generative-models

What kind of deep learning is the generation of numerical features (Y) from objects (X) used to compute a score (f(.), differentiable) that is to be maximized directly?
Basically NN<sub>$\theta$</sub>(x) = y, f(y) = score, so $\frac{d score}{d\theta} = \frac{dy}{d\theta} \frac{d f(y)}{dy}$ can be used for backpropagation; f(.) can be seen as a form of loss function.

This doesn't seem like supervised learning as no label exists for $x$. A good one could be found, but the best label score-wise isn't known and the search shouldn't be guided with potentially sub-optimal $y$s.

This isn't reinforcement learning, as the score is differentiable and used for backprop; there is also no sequential decision-making.

Is this a form of deep unsupervised learning? Self-supervised learning?

Comment: It seems like you have a direct evaluation of how good the mapping from X to Y is, in the form of the final score f(y) - this seems like supervised learning to me. Supervised learning doesn't use labels for the input features X, the supervision comes in knowing whether the downstream result Y was correct or not.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This reminds me of clustering, a classic unsupervised task: a cluster proposition is evaluated with a score (average distance) and iteratively improved (K-means). 
The deep unsupervised learning literature is not easy to parse and often not as simple as this problem, so I'll try fitting this deep learning situation to more classic unsupervised learning settings.